# Register values with useForm and react-select-country-list

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-hook-form

I have tried different options already to make this simple Select to work, but at this point I am not really sure if its possible.
the use-react-hook documentation doesn’t give me any answer with this case.

I want to basically 'register' what is it in 'value':

```
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import countryList from "react-select-country-list";
import Select from "react-select";

export const Country = ({ register }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const options = useMemo(() => countryList().getData(), []);

  const changeHandler = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl>
      
        <FormLabel>Country</FormLabel>
      
      <Select options={options} value={value} onChange={changeHandler}  />
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

I am using *register* in the parent component, and the onSubmit function takes the data that is registered, that’s the reason why I want to register what the user has chosen in the Select.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Since the form state lives in your parent component, I would use the `useFormContext` hook to register inputs inside your child component(s). Then either use a combination of the `useEffect` hook and your `changeHandler` function to register and update the field value, or use the built in `useController` hook.

Documentation for both can be found at:
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext
https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller